# TYPO3: How can I use the same slug for news on a multidomain setup?

Tags: routes, slug, tx-news, typo3-9.x

I have an issue with duplicate slugs for news on a multidomain setup and hope you can help me :).

My setup includes a single TYPO3 9.5.5 instance with multiple page trees like:

```
root
 domain.xyz
   - news
       - article
   - impress
   - news storage
   - ...
 domain.abc
   - news
       - article
   - impress
   - news storage
   - ...
```

So every domain/ website has a own news ecosystem. So currently my setup generates Urls like this:

- https://domain.xyz/news/article/xyz
- https://domain.abc/news/article/xyz

This is exactly what I want so far, but if I visit the detail page of https://domain.xyz/news/article/xyz then I get the wrong content of the news, because I get the content of https://domain.abc/news/article/xyz instead. So the issue occurs if a slug of "domain.xyz" is equal to a slug of "domain.abc".

If I change the slug of the second domain then everything is working fine. So is it possible to have same slugs on different domains?

I am using TYPO3 9.5.5 and news 7.2.0 and the site configuration of each domain contains the following route enhancer for news:

```
routeEnhancers:
 NewsPlugin:
   type: Extbase
   extension: News
   plugin: Pi1
   routes:
     -
       routePath: '{news_title}'
       _controller: 'News::detail'
       _arguments:
         news_title: news
   defaultController: 'News::detail'
   aspects:
     news_title:
       type: PersistedAliasMapper
       tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
       routeFieldName: path_segment
```

Comment: I guess that the plugins used on the news detail pages `/news/article/` are using their dedicated news storage folders. If that assumption is correct it's not related to routing, but to selecting the correct result set among all `tx_news_domain_model_news` records - for `listAction` only those in dedicated storage folders and for `detailAction` "all" storage folders.
However, this also would lead to duplicate content concerning news URLs.

Comment: Yes, they are using their dedicated news storage folders and I think you're right. In the mean time I have added the uid of the news to the url part of each news. Is not exactly what I want, but it's ok for me.